# What's the recommended way to programmatically play an audio stream using iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, audio, avaudioplayer

I have an mp3 on a remote server.  Want to play it as a stream, using my own UI,and my own ViewController.

How would you recommend doing that?

Comment: That's a possible starting point: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2-SW6, and specifically look under `Parsing Streamed Audio`

Comment: How about embedding an invisibale UIWebView, and let it play the mp3?  has anyone done that?  can I control the audio volume somehow?

Comment: UIWebView will not playback or more accurately will not "loadRequest" unless it is attached to a visible window. It is possible however to point to a mp3 file URL within UIWebView in order to play it - I think QuickTime plug-in will automatically take control of playback which means the standard controls will become visible to the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the code from this page to make a streamer, and it worked well, and was easy to implement.

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/revisiting-old-post-streaming-and.html